# Up Arrow + Left Arrow + Spacebar is not working

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

On an Ubuntu system I tried to get the pressed keys in JavaScript. I noticed that it's not possible to detect the SPACE key when UP ARROW and LEFT ARROW are pressed at the same moment. How can I figure out why it's blocked?

Same behavior with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Is it perhaps the same everywhere? It is probable that it is a hardware limitation in the keyboard. Can you try it somewhere else as well?

Comment: 12.04. Have no other machine here. But same behavior outside a browser.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a limitation of your keyboard. It is commonplace for keyboards to have "zones" to hedge the costs of making keyboards. Is this only in your browsers? If it is, then it's not the keyboard. But if it happens everywhere, then try another keyboard, as in a different brand and model. If you're using PS/2 try USB, if you're using USB try PS/2. If you want to buy a keyboard that never has this problem, look for something that is PS/2 and has N-Key Rollover.